# How to calculate sensitivity based on the width/height of the screen?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here's my idea: I wanted to have a scrollview where the user could both scroll the component in it, *and* click on it.

After hours of testing/search, I've finally managed to make this working with the following code.

My problem is in the comparison `Math.Abs(eventData.delta.x) > 1.0f`. I consider that if the mouse "moves more than `1.0f`" then it's dragging, else I consider this as a click.

The value **`1.0f`** works perfectly on all the devices with a mouse = it's easy ***not*** to move, and big screen (tablets), when you click. But on smartphones, ie my Galaxy S6 or the 3 other ones I've tried, it's very sensitive and almost impossible to make a click.

How could you programmatically handle this? Is there a DPI or something to take in account and based on this, multiply my **`1.0f`** by the resolution?

```
public class BoardHandler : EventTrigger
{
    private static GameObject _itemDragged;
    private static bool _isDragging;
    private static ScrollRect _scrollRect;

    public override void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData data)
    {
        if (_isDragging) {
            return;
        }
        Debug.Log("Click");
    }
    public override void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(eventData.delta.x) > 1.0f ||
            Math.Abs(eventData.delta.y) > 1.0f) {
            _scrollRect.OnBeginDrag(eventData);
            _isDragging = true;
        }
    }
    public override void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (_isDragging) {
            _scrollRect.OnDrag(eventData);
        }
    }
    public override void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (!_isDragging) {
            return;
        }
        _scrollRect.OnEndDrag(eventData);
        _isDragging = false;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        _scrollRect = GetComponentInParent<ScrollRect>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used TouchScript in the past to cover multiple devices within one project, like from 9 screens 6k screen array to tablets. They have a set of utilities to handle multiple resolution and dpi.

Check out the the UpdateResolution method in [TouchManagerInstance](https://github.com/TouchScript/TouchScript/blob/master/Source/Assets/TouchScript/Scripts/Core/TouchManagerInstance.cs).

hth.